# Continue search in another sheet where previous cell left off

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

1. Cell `C19` in a sheet looks up a certain word in cell `B3`
2. Cell `C19` also checks whether there is a `Yes` in another sheet according to criteria in B3 in relative column 140 in that other sheet. If this is the case, it writes `Yes` in the cell, otherwise it writes `Not reported` (the formula: `=IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-1'!$B$5:$ATN$217,140)="","Not reported",IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-1'!$B$5:$ATN$217,140)=0,"Not reported",(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-1'!$B$5:$ATN$217,140))))`)
3. Cell `B20` then checks if there is a `Yes` in cell `C19`
4. If this is the case, cell `B20` will lookup what is in cell `B3`and match de word to the line of another sheet (`some_sheet-2`), and if the result is a `Yes` in that cell, it will print out the header of the corresponding result.
5. If it does encounters a `No`, it will go to the next designated column and look for a `Yes` and so on until it finds one, if not it will write `Not applicable or no data submitted`

The formula in cell `B20`:

```
=IF($C$19="Yes",IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,7)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$H$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,11)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$l$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,15)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$P$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,19)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$T$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,23)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$X$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,27)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AB$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,31)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AF$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,35)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AJ$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,39)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AN$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,43)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AR$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,47)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AV$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,51)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$AZ$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,55)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$BF$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,59)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$BH$4,IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,'some_sheet-2'!$B$5:$BO$217,63)="Yes",'some_sheet-2'!$BL$4,""))))))))))))))),"Not applicable or no data submitted")
```

That was the easy part…

Now, what I need is that cell `B21` does (almost) the same as the formula in cell `B20`. The twist is that it should 'take off' where cell `B20` left.

What cell `B21` should do:

1. Check if cell `B20` contains the words `Not applicable or no data submitted`
2. If this is the case, stop there (leave the cell blank)
3. If it contains one of the column titles of `some_sheet-2`, go to the next column and do what cell `B20` was doing…
4. Then what cell `B21` does could be repeated over and over…

I realised that in order for cell `B21` to find out where to begin, this should be defined. I therefore created a formula in cell `A20` that looks up what appears in cell `B20` and finds the address of that cell in `some_sheet-2`:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX('some_sheet-2'!$H$4:$BL$4,MATCH(B20,'some_sheet-2'!$H$4:$BL$4,0)))
```

Does anyone have an idea what formula to write in order to realise the above mentioned (without resorting to VBA)?

Comment: You seem to already be familiar with index-match.  I would suggest changing the really long imbedded "if" statements to an index-match on the criteria you are looking for.  I think you could also use index-match to find where B20 ended with a certain criteria and continue it in B21.

Comment: @Evan_Callahan: Thank you very much for your remarks. However, as the "really long imbedded 'if' statements" functions, I will not change it (it is not really my priority right now). Regarding the INDEX-MATCH, it looks like I am familiar with them, but unfortunately not really (I probably found the basis somewhere on the web and adapted without really understanding its nuts & bolts), hence my question here… Thank you for your understanding :-)

Comment: In order to continue the function of B20 in B21 where it left off you could use "indirect(A20)" since you already have a function in A20 to find the cell reference where B20 ended.  Let's say B20 references E20:Z20 but ended at H20.  Well your formulas above should have the value "$H$20" in cell A20 so if you use "Indirect(A20) : Z20" as the range for B21 with the formula from B20 then it will continue the formula with the new range being from where B20 ended.  I hope this helps

Comment: Tried to follow your advice of your 1st comment @Evan Callahan transforming the VLOOKUPs of cell B20 into index-match, however I don't see the advantage because it almost doubles the length of the algorithm: `=IF(INDEX('ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$H:$BL,MATCH($B$3,'ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$B:$B,0),MATCH("Yes",'ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$H:$H,0))="Yes",'ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$H$4,IF(INDEX('ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$H:$BL,MATCH($B$3,'ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$B:$B,0),MATCH("Yes",'ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$L:$L,0))="Yes",'ATLAS 2017 multisect_coll'!$H$4,etc…))`
Can you advise?

Comment: It might be longer, but is usually better practice to use index-match rather than vlookup.  The first is in your original formula you have it referencing column number 140 in the array which is prone to error.  Also if you insert any columns to your data set that 140 will no longer correspond to the correct column where index match will update itself with the new range.  It will usually be a bit longer, but in your case is significantly longer because of how many if's you are looking at.  Also it won't be that noticeable but index-match has a slightly faster processing speed than vlookup.

Comment: @EvanCallahan . Comment well understood, and thank you. Will do as suggested. And also I imagine I could better recycle that formula for the next stage (the question of this thread). Can I kindly ask you to give me a hand on this one as I am a bit overwhelmed by the issue? I guess that my problem is that I don't know where to insert the cell A20 result with an INDIRECT(A20) statement in the algorithm… or did I totally miss the point of your corresponding post of yesterday?

Comment: It seems the INDEX-MATCH algorithm does not function the way I want (it gives me wrong results). Formula:
    `=INDEX(B4:P25,MATCH(B28,A:A,0),MATCH("Yes",B:B,0))`  
    `B4:P25` = the array
    `MATCH(B28,A:A,0)` = find what is in cell `B28` (say the word `AA`) with the content of column `A` which gives me the row number (in this case `4`)
    `MATCH("Yes",B:B,0)` = find word `Yes` in column `B` that corresponds to the row given in the previous `MATCH` (in this case `4` also).
But crossing between row 4 and column 4 is not at all what I wanted: a `NO`, but I wanted the `Yes` found in B4

Comment: The intersection of row 4 and column 4 is going to correspond with the original array B4:P25. It should be grabbing cell E7 based on the formula now.  If you want it to be grabbing the information elsewhere then you have to change that first array.

Comment: As for indirect(A20) if the value in A20 from your formula is $E$10 then indirect(A20):P25 will give you the array E10:P25

Comment: Formula `VLOOKUP` replaced by `INDEX-MATCH`. Now, I have to start using the cell analysing the address of the where the above mentioned formula left off. What I did is copy-pasting the `INDEX-MATCH` formula that replaces the `VLOOKUP` one and replacing the portion that references the row as follows:  
`=IF(INDEX($B$2:$P$23,MATCH($C$25,$A$2:$A$23,0),MATCH("Collab01",`$B$1`:$P$1,0))="Yes",$B$1,IF(etc…`  

with the cell that finds where the last analysis finished (`A20`), like so:  

`=IF(INDEX($B$2:$P$23,MATCH($C$25,$A$2:$A$23,0),MATCH("Collab01",`$A$20`:$P$1,0))="Yes",$B$1,IF(etc…`

Comment: But obviously, it does not work. So the question is:  
how to replace an array (say `MATCH("Collab‌​01",$B$1:$P$1,0)` - the `$B$1:$P$1` portion) with `MATCH("Collab‌​01",$A$20+1:$P$1,0)`, where `$A$20+1` is the cell that gives the cell address where we left off and to which we add 1 cell number.  

Say the algorithm left at cell `$J$1` (mentioned in cell `$A$20`) and we have to start from the following cell `$K$1`…